# Disable Radio Button If Field Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an `asp.net` website and on the contact us form, there are 2 fields (Tel No. & Email Address) and also 2 radio buttons (Preferred contact method - Tel/Email). What I'm after is having the radio buttons disabled when these fields are empty and enable them if they have a value in them.

I want the radio buttons to become enabled when ever the user starts typing in these fields and if they then remove the value, for them ot be disabled so I know it needs to be done ether using JQuery or JavaScript but no sure how to do this.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="TelFieldLabel" class="col-md-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Contact No." AssociatedControlID="TelField"></asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TelField" runat="server" class="form-control" type="Number"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="EmailFieldLabel" class="col-md-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Email address" AssociatedControlID="EmailField"></asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="EmailField" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="EmailField" ErrorMessage="Please enter your email address." />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" SetFocusOnError="True" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="EmailField" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">Email address is not a valid format.</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </div>
    </div>    
<asp:Label runat="server" class="radio-inline">
         <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="phone" value="Phone" GroupName="prefcontact"/> Phone
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:Label runat="server" class="radio-inline">
         <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="email" value="Email" GroupName="prefcontact"/> Email
    </asp:Label>
```

Comment: where is the text input box ?

Comment: This might give you an idea: http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/jquery-disable-button/

Comment: @joyBlanks Sorry I hadn't wrapped it in my code snippet so it wasn't displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please view this post for the fix i found ([JQuery Not Disabling My Radio Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066530/jquery-not-disabling-my-radio-buttons))

Answer (score 1):

Use Below snippets of code

```js
$('input[type="text"]').bind('blur', function(e) {

  if($('#telNo').val().length > 0 || $('#email').val().length > 0){
  
    $('input[type="radio"]').prop('disabled', false);  
    
  }else {
    $('input[type="radio"]').prop('disabled', true);  
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Tel. No : <input type="text" id="telNo" /><br >
  Email : <input type="text" id="email" /><br>
  
  Preferred contact method : 
  <input type="radio" name="preferred" disabled />Tel
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="preferred" disabled />Email
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xqfr4na6/1/

You can use `input propertychange paste` to change the radio button status while typing in the textbox. With this solution you don't need to wait for control to go out of textbox which `blur` function does.

```js
    $('input[type="text"]').on('input propertychange paste', function () {
    if ($('#telNo').val().length > 0 || $('#email').val().length > 0) {
        $('input[type="radio"]').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('input[type="radio"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Tel No.:
    <input type="text" id="telNo" />&nbsp;Email Address:
    <input type="text" id="email" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="preferred" disabled />Phone
    <input type="radio" name="preferred" disabled />Email</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using Jquery.

```
$('#txtPhone').on('input',function(e){

 if($('#txtPhone').val().length == 0){

 $("#phone input:radio").attr('disabled',true);
 $("#email input:radio").attr('disabled',true);

 }
else{
$( '#phone input[type="radio"]' ).removeAttr( "disabled" );
$( '#email input[type="radio"]' ).removeAttr( "disabled" );

} 

});
```