# JQuery Not Disabling My Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net website which I have some code which if my Tel or Email field are blank then y 'Tel' and 'Email' radio button is disabled but the issue I have is that I when I hit the page, the radio buttons are not disabling.  I have tried using all the extensions on the following webpage but still nothing
(https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('input[type="Number"]').on('input propertychange paste', function () 
     {
          if ($('#MainContent_TelField').val().length > 0)
          {
               $('#MainContent_phone').prop('disabled', false);
          }
          else
          {
               $('#MainContent_phone').prop('disabled', true);    
          }
     });

     $('input[type="Text"]').on('input propertychange paste', function ()
     {
          if ($('#MainContent_EmailField').val().length > 0)
          {
               $('#MainContent_email').prop('disabled', false);
          }
          else
          {
               $('#MainContent_email').prop('disabled', true);
          }
     });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="form-group">
                 <asp:Label ID="TelFieldLabel" class="col-md-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Contact No." AssociatedControlID="TelField"></asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TelField" runat="server" class="form-control" type="Number"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="EmailFieldLabel" class="col-md-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Email address" AssociatedControlID="EmailField"></asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="EmailField" runat="server" class="form-control" type="Text"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="EmailField" ErrorMessage="Please enter your email address." />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" SetFocusOnError="True" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="EmailField" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">Email address is not a valid format.</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientclick="ShowProcessingPopup();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Submit</asp:LinkButton>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I guess you want something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/jv0yyhnb/2/)

Comment: @Abhi Could you please add this as an answer so i can mark it and accept it as its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  function checkTelField(){
    if ($('#MainContent_TelField').val().length > 0)
          {
               $('#MainContent_phone').prop('disabled', false);
          }
          else
          {
               $('#MainContent_phone').prop('disabled', true);    
          }
  }
  function checkEmailField(){
    if ($('#MainContent_EmailField').val().length > 0)
          {
               $('#MainContent_email').prop('disabled', false);
          }
          else
          {
               $('#MainContent_email').prop('disabled', true);
          }
  }
  checkTelField();
  checkEmailField();
 });
     $('input[type="Number"]').on('input propertychange paste', function () 
     {
          if ($('#MainContent_TelField').val().length > 0)
          {
               $('#MainContent_phone').prop('disabled', false);
          }
          else
          {
               $('#MainContent_phone').prop('disabled', true);    
          }
     });

     $('input[type="Text"]').on('input propertychange paste', function ()
     {  
          if ($('#MainContent_EmailField').val().length > 0)
          {
               $('#MainContent_email').prop('disabled', false);
          }
          else
          {
               $('#MainContent_email').prop('disabled', true);
          }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="MainContent_TelField" id="MainContent_TelFieldLabel" class="col-md-3 control-label">Contact No.</label>
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <input name="ctl00$MainContent$TelField" id="MainContent_TelField" class="form-control" type="Number" />
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="MainContent_EmailField" id="MainContent_EmailFieldLabel" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email address</label>
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <input name="ctl00$MainContent$EmailField" id="MainContent_EmailField" class="form-control" type="Text" />
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <span id="MainContent_PrefContactLabel" class="col-md-3 control-label">Preferred method of contact *</span>
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <span class="radio-inline">
               <input id="MainContent_phone" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$prefcontact" value="Phone" /> Phone
          </span>
          <span class="radio-inline">
                <input id="MainContent_email" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent $prefcontact" value="Email" /> Email
          </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable your option buttons from the beginning when the page loads. Right now, you are trying to disable it only when there is some input in the boxes. This is what you should do:

```
$('#MainContent_phone').prop('disabled', true);
$('#MainContent_email').prop('disabled', true);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jv0yyhnb/2/)

Comment: I have an issue if my form fails validation as it re-disables my radio buttons alhtough my Tel/Email field still contain my initial value and due to this i can't submit my form as it says i haven't selected a radio  button.  How do i fix this this was you fiddle i used http://jsfiddle.net/jv0yyhnb/2/.      I have also updated my HTML to show my validation messages if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in [document-ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler.

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

*Use*

```
 $(function () {
    $('input[type="Number"]').on('input propertychange paste', function ()  {
        //Rest of the code
    })
 })
```